# pyopenssl export certificate and private key to a pkcs#12 chain

Tags: python, openssl, pyopenssl

I'm trying to export a ca cert, client cert and a private key to a pkcs#12 chain but can't get it to work at all. This is my code so far:

```
def pem_to_pfx(self, pem_ca_path, pem_path, encrypted_key_path, new_pw, p12_path):
    with open(encrypted_key_path, 'rb') as f:
        encrypted_key_file = f.read()
    with open(pem_ca_path, 'r') as f:
        ca_cert_file = f.read()
    with open(pem_path, 'r') as f:
        user_cert_file = f.read()
    ca_cert = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, ca_cert_file)
    user_cert = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, user_cert_file)
    encrypted_key = crypto.load_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, encrypted_key_file, passphrase=new_pw.encode('ascii'))
    p12 = OpenSSL.crypto.PKCS12()
    p12.set_privatekey(encrypted_key)
    p12.set_ca_certificates(ca_cert)
    p12.set_certificate(user_cert)
    open(p12_path, 'wb').write(p12.export(passphrase=new_pw))
```

This does not work for some reason and i can't figure out why exactly. The error it gives me is:

```
line 54, in exception_from_error_queue
    raise exception_type(errors)
OpenSSL.crypto.Error: [('Provider routines', '', 'bad decrypt'), ('PKCS12 routines', '', 'pkcs12 cipherfinal error'), ('Provider routines', '', 'bad decrypt'), ('PKCS12 routines', '', 'pkcs12 cipherfinal error')]
```

I can't understand why it wouldnt work. The key is exported in earlier function with PKCS-8 AES-256-CBC.

Answer (score 0):

The error came from the password input. After i solved the password it worked wonders.

The updated code:

```
def pem_to_pfx(self, pem_ca_path, pem_path, encrypted_key_path, p12_path):
    with open(encrypted_key_path, 'rb') as f:
        encrypted_key_file = f.read()
    with open(pem_ca_path, 'r') as f:
        ca_cert_file = f.read()
    with open(pem_path, 'r') as f:
        user_cert_file = f.read()
    ca_cert = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, ca_cert_file)
    user_cert = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, user_cert_file)
    encrypted_key = crypto.load_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, encrypted_key_file, passphrase=passphrase.encode('ascii'))
    p12 = OpenSSL.crypto.PKCS12()
    p12.set_privatekey(encrypted_key)
    p12.set_ca_certificates([ca_cert, user_cert])
    #p12.set_certificate(user_cert)
    open(p12_path, 'wb').write(p12.export(passphrase=passphrase))

    if os.path.exists(pem_path):
        os.remove(pem_path)

    if os.path.exists(pem_ca_path):
        os.remove(pem_ca_path)

    if os.path.exists(encrypted_key_path):
        os.remove(encrypted_key_path)
```